# How to configure Apache for topojson gzip files

Tags: leaflet, apache, topojson, compression

Building an online interactive map with leaflet and some heavy layers with my spatial data in topojson format. I have been reading about gzip but I am still uncertain how to configure it.

Do I need to:

1. gzip the files used for my leaflet map myself in my terminal ?
2. change my javascript code so that instead of calling 1966.topojson I call 1966.topojson.gz ?
3. change the apache server (2nd generation) in some way?

Not sure how to change it so that it can send topojson files.

Is there any good tutorial around for that?

Answer (score 1):

You do not compress them manually yourself, instead you configure Apache to compress them on the fly when browsers request/allow that. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254859/does-apache-2-gzip-json-output-by-default